# Get filename of filetype object in iframe by jquery after choose file clicked

Tags: jquery, post, iframe

I used this code for example in (**main.php**):

```
<input type="text" ID"inp"/>

<iframe src="sample.php?" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" style="direction: ltr; border:none;min-height:80px;" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

and **sample.php** :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:9px">
<input type="file" name="flbannerpic" accept="image/*"  align="left" style="max-width:190px;" />
<input  type="submit"  value="upload" align="left" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

I need set **inp** value to file name selected in **main.php** by jquery  or without jquery (optional) after file selected in iframe (**sample.php**) [before upload] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need iframe there?. Without iframes it is an easy task.

If at all you need iframe and still want to do this:

Write a onchange function for file input in the sample.php

```
function setFilename(name) {
    window.parent.fillFilename(name);
}
```

and in the main.php

```
function fillFilename(name) {
    document.getElementById("inp").value = name;
}
```